# Implementing m-m or 1-m relationships in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I am new to JPA. I want two of my tables to have 1-m relationship. I am seeing many examples that have something like a containment on the owning side. for example if I have two tables User and Blog, then class User will have a private field naming Collection.

What I am interested in knowing is, instead of storing entire object can I create something like Collection blogId (in User class), and this blogId would refer to primary key in Blog?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

JPA (or other ORM frameworks) are supposed to let you think about objects and relations between them, not tables and foreign keys. I do not think you want to do what you are asking.

The `User` entity should have a collection of `Blog` entities which could if you want have a reference back to the User in the form of a field `user`. But that is up to you and your needs. If you start creating entities with fields that contains `foreign keys` instead of object references you have misunderstood some of the concept that ORM is trying to solve for you. You will also lose some of the functions and capabilities that the JPA is giving you such as cascading updates, fetching etc. that you probably want. You can also use the annotations to decide if you want to use a foreign key column on the "many-side" or if you want to use a join table.

In your underlying table you would of course have foreign keys as you normally would have done if you did not use an ORM. You use the JPA annotations to alter the default foreign key column names JPA normally except if you already have a table scheme in place, or if you are not satisfied with the naming conventions that JPA uses.

This link should provide you with enough information about one-to-many relationships in JPA. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany

Answer (score 0):

to do what you want I suggest is this:

```
class User{
...
@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
private List<Blog> blogs;
...
}
```

in this why JPA won't load entire `blogs`; instead, it will be loaded on demand. e.g. when you do this `blogs.get(0).getOtherField()` JPA will load needed data with another query.

Comment: The DEFAULT fetch for 1-N is LAZY, no need to specify it

Comment: @BillyFrost you are right; however, mentioning it can make code more readable.